# Change src video attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying this solution to change video src with jquery but it doesn't work. It still load the html inline video source.

HTML:

```
  <video id="lanvid" autoplay  class="lanvid"
   poster="img/Nuraghes_main.jpg" id="bgvid2"  loop >
        <source id="mp4Source" src="img/clouds.mp4" />        
  </video>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var player = document.getElementsById('lanvid');
var mp4vid = document.getElementsById('mp4Source');

player.pause();

$(mp4Vid).attr('src', "img/about.mp4");

  player.load();
  player.play();


  });
```

Comment: have you tried `$("#mp4Source").attr('src', "img/about.mp4");`?

Comment: It works Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First not exist the method: "document.getElementsById", the correct method is "document.getElementById" without the "s" in the word "Element".

Second, the selector "mp4Vid" is not equal to "mp4vid", the "V" is different "v", javascript is case sensitive, therefore your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var player = document.getElementById('lanvid');
var mp4vid = document.getElementById('mp4Source');

player.pause();

$(mp4vid).attr('src', "img/about.mp4");

player.load();
player.play();

});
```

on the other hand, a better way to do this is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var player = document.getElementById('lanvid');

player.pause();

$('#mp4Source').attr('src', "img/about.mp4");

player.load();
player.play();

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Reddy , is fixed now my error.